# Redux Recipe List

Tags: react.js, jsx, redux

I made a simple React + Redux app which allows you to add and remove recipes to a list.

Here are the user stories the app fulfills:

> User Story: I can create recipes that have names and ingredients.
>
> User Story: I can see an index view where the names of all the recipes are visible.
>
> User Story: I can click into any of those recipes to view it.
>
> User Story: I can delete these recipes.

User Story: All new recipes I add are saved in my browser's local storage. If I refresh the page, these recipes will still be there.

Code:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore } from 'redux'

const ADD_RECIPE = 'ADD_RECIPE'
const SHOW_RECIPE = 'SHOW_RECIPE'
const EDIT_RECIPE = 'EDIT_RECIPE'
const UPDATE_ACTIVE_NAME = 'UPDATE_ACTIVE_NAME'
const UPDATE_ACTIVE_INGREDIENTS = 'UPDATE_ACTIVE_INGREDIENTS'
const TOGGLE_ACTIVE_ID = 'TOGGLE_ACTIVE_ID'
const DELETE_RECIPE = 'DELETE_RECIPE'

const initialState = {
  activeName: '',
  activeIngredients: '',
  activeId: '',
  recipes: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Pizza',
      ingredients: 'Dough, tomato, cheese, salt, pepper, olives, mushrooms, ham.'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Sherpherd\'s Pie',
      ingredients: 'Potato, lamb'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Huel Shake',
      ingredients: 'Milk, huel'
    }
  ]
}

// action creators
const saveStoreRecipesToLocalStorage = (state) => {
  localStorage.setItem('state', JSON.stringify(
    {...state, activeId: ""}
  ));
}

const getStoreRecipesFromLocalStorage = () => {
  const state = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('state'))
  return state.recipes.length && state
}

const addRecipe = (id, name, ingredients) => {
  return {
    type: ADD_RECIPE,
    payload: {
      id,
      name,
      ingredients
    }
  }
}

const updateActiveName = payload => {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_ACTIVE_NAME,
    payload
  }
}

const updateActiveIngredients = payload => {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_ACTIVE_INGREDIENTS,
    payload
  }
}

const toggleActiveId = id => {
  return {
    type: TOGGLE_ACTIVE_ID,
    payload: id
  }
}

const deleteRecipe = id => {
  return {
    type: DELETE_RECIPE,
    payload: id
  }
}

// reducer
function recipes (state = getStoreRecipesFromLocalStorage() || initialState, action) {
  console.warn('action:', action)
  switch (action.type) {
    case TOGGLE_ACTIVE_ID:
      return {...state, activeId: action.payload}
    case UPDATE_ACTIVE_NAME:
      return {...state, activeName: action.payload}
    case UPDATE_ACTIVE_INGREDIENTS:
      return {...state, activeIngredients: action.payload}
    case ADD_RECIPE:
      return {...state, recipes: [...state.recipes, action.payload]}
    case DELETE_RECIPE:
      return {...state, recipes: state.recipes.filter(recipe => recipe.id !== action.payload)}
    case EDIT_RECIPE:
      return
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const Recipes = (props) => {
  getStoreRecipesFromLocalStorage()
  const {addRecipe, updateActiveIngredients, updateActiveName, toggleActiveId, deleteRecipe, state} = props
  const id = new Date().getTime() / 1000
  return (
    <div style={{width: 320}}>
      <form onSubmit={e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        addRecipe(id, state.activeName, state.activeIngredients)
      }}>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Name"
          value={state.activeName}
          onChange={(e) => updateActiveName(e.target.value)}
        />
        <input
          placeholder="Ingredients"
          value={state.activeIngredients}
          onChange={e => updateActiveIngredients(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button type="submit">Add Recipe</button>
      </form>
      {state.recipes.map(item => <ul key={item.name}>
        <div style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
          <li onClick={() => toggleActiveId(item.id)}>
            <div>{item.name}</div>
            {state.activeId === item.id && <div>{item.ingredients}</div>}
          </li>
          <div style={{color: 'red'}} onClick={() => deleteRecipe(item.id)}>&times;</div>
        </div>
      </ul>)}

    </div>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    state
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    addRecipe: (id, name, ingredients) => {
      if (name && ingredients) {
        dispatch(addRecipe(id, name, ingredients))
        dispatch(updateActiveName(''))
        dispatch(updateActiveIngredients(''))
        saveStoreRecipesToLocalStorage(ownProps.store.getState())
      }
    },
    updateActiveName: name => dispatch(updateActiveName(name)),
    updateActiveIngredients: ingredients => dispatch(updateActiveIngredients(ingredients)),
    toggleActiveId: id => dispatch(toggleActiveId(id)),
    deleteRecipe: id => {
      dispatch(deleteRecipe(id))
      saveStoreRecipesToLocalStorage(ownProps.store.getState())
    }
  }
}

const App = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Recipes)

const store = createStore(recipes, window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__())
const render = () => ReactDOM.render(<App store={store}/>, document.getElementById('root'))
store.subscribe(render)
render()
```

I would like to structure the app better by splitting this file into separate files but for the sake of this question I have kept it in one file.

Demo (adapted for codepen without localStorage features): https://codepen.io/alanbuchanan/pen/LQWKBZ

Making this small app brought about some questions I have about Redux:

1. I have an `updateActiveName` and `updateActiveIngredients` function because there are only these two fields that get added by the form. Would it be better instead to use an `updateActiveObject` and run this when either field changes? I see this as a benefit for when other fields get added, but less efficient because I will be running an onChange function for several fields that aren't changing.
2. The naming of my action creators, reducers, and functions inside `mapDispatchToProps` are usually the same. For example `UPDATE_ACTIVE_INGREDIENTS`, `updateActiveIngredients` action creator and `updateActiveIngredients` function. Is there a better approach to this?
3. In the `addRecipe` function inside `mapDispatchToProps`, I am validating the `name` and `ingredients` values. Should this go inside this function, or somewhere else?
4. In the `addRecipe` function inside `mapDispatchToProps`, I am dispatching many actions. Is this correct practise?

Any other feedback for improving my Redux is most welcome.

Answer (score 2):

I've only started working with React/Redux myself, but here are my thoughts.

1. In my system I am saving the form values to local component state until the form is saved. I have one onChange handler method which checks which form field it is and then will setState.
2. This is something I also find with React/Redux - a lot of boilerplate and repetition to update a few pieces of data... Similar to yourself I have the Action Types / Action Creators / API Calls / Reducers / Component methods all with very similar names. I think that is just the way it is. I'm also looking to include redux-saga in our code so that potentially means even more of the same named methods.
3. I use parsley for form validating, so that code is handled by the library. If I really needed to do further checking, I would do it in the onChange before changing the local component state.
4. You have everything in one component at the moment for listing the recipes and adding the recipes. I would split them into separate components and then once you're finished with saving a new recipe, render the list again. Your app is very much like a To Do list app, have a look for examples of that.

If it wasn't for the speed of react-redux, I probably wouldn't be bothered with it!

Here's an example of a to do app that has a similar structure to my own app (which I hope is well structured lol).
https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/todomvc

Answer (score 1):

The one thing that I would change is that since you are already using `react-redux` library, you might as well do this -

```
let store = createStore(recipes, window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__())

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

So that you don't have to manually `subscribe` like so -

```
store.subscribe(render)
render()
```

---

---

About the questions that you mentioned -

> 1. I have an `updateActiveName` and `updateActiveIngredients` function because there are only these two fields that get added by the form. Would it be better instead to use an `updateActiveObject` and run this when either field changes? I see this as a benefit for when other fields get added, but less efficient because I will be running an `onChange` function for several fields that aren't changing.

This is again an opinion, but I wouldn't do that. One reason is that they don't/might not have similar types.

An example where this might work is - say - you have a big form where you have to enter a number of dates, one for birthdate, one for date of joining the company etc. You could a function `changeDate()/updateDate()` which would serve as a common function to update dates.

---

> 2. The naming of my action creators, reducers, and functions inside `mapDispatchToProps` are usually the same. For example `UPDATE_ACTIVE_INGREDIENTS`, `updateActiveIngredients` action creator and `updateActiveIngredients` function. Is there a better approach to this?

This is fine, so long as you stick with it. You anyways don't have to worry about the `ActionCreator` names because, if you access the methods/functions that are defined in `mapDispatchToProps()` and don't directly `dispatch()` actions in the `Component` itself, you wouldn't find much problems with understanding what goes where.

What I mean is, if you use - `this.props.updateActiveIngredients()` - then it is fine. However, if you use - `this.props.dispatch(updateActiveIngredients())` you might get confused.

---

> 3.In the `addRecipe` function inside `mapDispatchToProps`, I am validating the `name` and `ingredients` values. Should this go inside this function, or somewhere else?

Technically, it is a function. You can move it to a named function, but for something this small this is alright.

---

> 4.In the `addRecipe` function inside `mapDispatchToProps`, I am dispatching many actions. Is this correct practice?

This is correct. You can also add a `redux-thunk` middleware and add an `ActionCreator` that returns a function instead of a simple JSON object.

For e.g.:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    addRecipe: (id, name, ingredients) => {
      if (name && ingredients) {
        dispatch(addRecipe(id, name, ingredients))
        dispatch(updateActiveName(''))
        dispatch(updateActiveIngredients(''))
        saveStoreRecipesToLocalStorage(ownProps.store.getState())
      }
    }
  }
}
```

could be replaced by something like this -

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
    addRecipe: (id, name, ingredients) => dispatch(addRecipe(id, name, ingredients))
  }
}
// Action Creator
addRecipe(id, name, ingredients) => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    if (name && ingredients) {
      dispatch(addRecipe(id, name, ingredients))
      dispatch(updateActiveName(''))
      dispatch(updateActiveIngredients(''))
      // Get the proper state that you want using getState()
      const something = getState()
      saveStoreRecipesToLocalStorage(something)
    }
  }
}
```